# Asp.Net Core 3.1 - Get Image from directory and display in razor view?

Tags: html, asp.net, image, asp.net-core, razor-pages

How can I take the image from the directory and display it?

"I saw similar posts but it did not help"

I did this but it didn't work

Controller :

```
     string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(_hostingEnv.WebRootPath, @"site\img\banner\"));          
       
        ViewBag.ListImgMainDefalt = filePaths;
```

View :

```
foreach (var item in ViewBag.ListImgMainDefalt)
                    {
                        <tr>                               

                            <td>
                                <img src="@item" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    }
```

Resault :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like below:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(_hostingEnv.WebRootPath, @"site\img\banner\"));
List<string> fileName = new List<string>();
foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
{
    fileName.Add(@"/site/img/banner/"+Path.GetFileName(filePath));
}
ViewBag.ListImgMainDefalt = fileName;
```